# edit layout of existing child in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout with a number of children. The RelativeLayout is the main layout of my activity. I need to add to one of the children the layout value `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. I need to do this programmatically. the link [How to set the android property layout_alignParentBottom to a button dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914590/how-to-set-the-android-property-layout-alignparentbottom-to-a-button-dynamically) is not working for me because, basically, I don't want to have to inflate the RelativeLayout as I already have it at the `setContentView(...)`. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: are you adding the subview with addView on the RelativeLayout viewgroup?

Comment: @akhalsa I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = (LayoutParams) theChild.getLayoutParams();
layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```