# How to inflate view to bottom

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-inflate, android-relativelayout

I am trying to dynamically inflate a tabhost to the bottom of a view; however, no matter what I do it gets sent to the top.

```
    RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.messagesactivityview);
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottombartabs, null);
    item.addView(child);
    maketabs();
```

this is the code I'm using to inflate and here is the xml file of the tabhost I'm trying to inflate(note thatI've set layout_alignParentBottom to true, but it still does not work)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhosty"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/switchtomessages"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-3.5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-3.5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/messages_icon" >
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/switchtorequests"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-3.5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-3.5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/friend_request_icon" >
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/switchtofriends"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-3.5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-3.5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/friends_icon" >
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/uselesstab"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-3.5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-3.5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/settings_icon" >
</ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

how do I send it to the bottom

Comment: you other layout. the one in which you are inflating this layout, is it a Relative layout?

Comment: Try Setting it in code instead of xml, see example here <br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914590/how-to-set-the-android-property-layout-alignparentbottom-to-a-button-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the code to

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.messagesactivityview);
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottombartabs, item);
```

without any known parent, all LayoutParams you declared on the root element of your XML tree will just get thrown away.

Comment: Why should they?  Please explain why this is valid.